# What is the result of true && true && true && false && true && true && true in javascript?

Tags: javascript, logic, conditional-operator, adobe-indesign, extendscript

Should the following:

`true && true && true && false && true && true && true`

(with 6 "trues" and 1 "false" in the middle, all connected by `&&`) result in `true` or `false`? The program I'm using, Adobe InDesign (which uses a JavaScript-based scripting language), gives `true`? Also how do you calculated the result of a conditional that consists of lots of "trues" and "falses"?

Comment: `InDesign` is broken according to JavaScript standards, but then that's why it's not JavaScript.

Comment: Probably, but here is just a simplification, my original conditional is a lot jankier so it's probably tripping up InDesign.

Comment: I can't say because I cannot *see* your "original conditional".

Comment: @Pointy It's contextual only to InDesign and only to the script I'm writing. There's no way I can easily make sense of it here.

Comment: Okay, this is purely a user error on my part. I've finally found the one typo that causes all this confusion.

Comment: The following code using a ternary operator in InDesign alerts _false_ as expected:  `true && true && true && false && true && true && true ? alert("true") : alert("false") `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a conforming JavaScript implementation, *any* sequence of the form (x<sub>1</sub> [&& x<sub>2</sub>]*) is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) if *any* expression x<sub>N</sub> is falsy — it evaluates to the first falsy x<sub>N</sub> value (or last x<sub>N</sub> if none are falsy), via leftward association of `&&`.

Leftward association means `(x1 && x2 && …)` is equivalent to `((x1 && x2) && …)`, which can trivially be applied to the expression originally shown to determine that the “expected” result in JavaScript is `false`.

This conjunction behavior is expected behavior in most programming languages.

If “other operators” are mixed in, in “ways not shown”, it’s possible the premise in the question is not accurate due to precedence rules. Note that each x<sub>N</sub> above is unambiguous, by substitution. Likewise, if it’s not a conforming JavaScript engine…

Answer (score 1):

it will be false

```js
console.log(true && true && true && false && true && true && true)
```